# Looping conditional formatting.

Tags: google-apps-script

I want this code to loop through all columns in the sheet.  I am a teacher and would like to use this code to grade spreadsheets but right now the code only works for column G.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function conditional() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()+1;
    var numC = sheet.getLastColumn(); 

for (var t = 7; t = numC; t++){
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,t,numRows,1);
    var answer = sheet.getRange(2,t).getValue();
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
   .whenTextEqualTo(answer)
   .setBackground("#00ff00")
   .setFontColor("#00ff00")
   .setRanges([range])
   .build();
   var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
   rules.push(rule);
   sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

   var rule2 = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
  .whenTextDoesNotContain(answer)
  .setBackground("#ff0000")
  .setFontColor("#ff0000")
  .setRanges([range])
  .build();
   var rules2 = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
   rules2.push(rule2);
   sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules2);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Review the Spreadsheet Service methods if you are unsure what arguments are given to specific class methods. Being a teacher is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, just trying to say I am a newbie at this.

Comment: a good place to start is by reading the Apps Script docs on the class methods used by your existing script, such that you could explain to your class what each line means. For some lines you may need to review a JavaScript language reference (such as MDN or W3Schools).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your for loop, you have to change the for loop as follows.

```
for (var t = 1; t <= numC; t++)
```

Here what I did is, I have modified the for loop syntax to iterate from column A till the last columns.

Comment: That is still only formatting column G.  I left t = 7 because this is where I want the formatting to begin.

Comment: okay note that I have changes `t = numC` to `t <= numC` in for loop.

Comment: I changed them.  It still only formats the column G